# Why was my list altered after last function call?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linked-list, member

I have a class `Polynomial` defined as

```
   template<typename, T>
   class Polynomial{
      Monomial<T> *head;
   public:
      Polynomial(Monomial<T> *p=NULL){ head=p;}
      Polynomial insert(T c, int n){
        Monomial<T>*q=new Monomial<T>(c,n);
        Monomial<T> *p=head, *t=NULL;
        while(p!=NULL && q->pw < p->pw) { t=p; p=p->next;}
        if(t==NULL){q->next=head; head=q; }
        else{ t->next = q;  q->next=p; }   
        return *this;
      }
      T evaluate(T x){
        T sum=0;
        for(Monomial<T>* p=head; p!=NULL; p=p->next)
            sum+=p->evaluate(x);
        return sum;
      }
   };
```

where `Monomial` is a linked list using struct. In my main function I have

```
    10    int main(){
    20        Polynomial<int> p;
    30        cout<<p.insert(1,2).insert(2,3).insert(2,1).insert(4,5).evaluate(2);
    40        p.destroy();
    50    }
```

I have break points at line 30 and 40 and at line 40 while debugging I realized that although my output was correct, the list I have in `p` wasn't the one I expected, it was like only the first `insert(1,2)` was called. So I put breakpoints in the `insert` and `evaluate` members and I observed that all the `insert`s were done before `evaluate` was called and after that my list returned to its state after the first insertion `insert(1,2)`.

I really don't understand why this happened because after separating the `insert` calls like this

```
     30     p.insert(1,2);    p.insert(2,3);    p.insert(2,1);    p.insert(4,5);
     40     cout<<p.evaluate(2);
```

I got what I wanted but what is the difference between these two methods and why is the first one not giving me what I wanted (that is all insertion were present).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the return value of the `insert` method to a reference:

```
Polynomial & insert(T c, int n);
```

What you have now creates a copy of the object when returning from this function and the subsequent calls insert values into the copy.

Answer (score 4):

In

```
 Polynomial insert(T c, int n){ // <- returns the value which cannot be chained
    Monomial<T>*q=new Monomial<T>(c,n);
    Monomial<T> *p=head, *t=NULL;
    while(p!=NULL && q->pw < p->pw) { t=p; p=p->next;}
    if(t==NULL){q->next=head; head=q; }
    else{ t->next = q;  q->next=p; }   
    return *this;
  }
```

you are returning `*this` -> okay, but if you want to use it as chained, you must return a reference like

```
  Polynomial& insert(T c, int n){ // <- see the Polynomial&, returns reference, which can be chained
    Monomial<T>*q=new Monomial<T>(c,n);
    Monomial<T> *p=head, *t=NULL;
    while(p!=NULL && q->pw < p->pw) { t=p; p=p->next;}
    if(t==NULL){q->next=head; head=q; }
    else{ t->next = q;  q->next=p; }   
    return *this;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because the insert returns Polynomial. Try to return a reference:

```
Polynomial &insert(T c, int n){
```

With returning Polynomial, insert always return a copy of the object itself. So line 30 makes many copies of the original p, but p is unchanged.